# Error while inserting transaction in hyperledger explorer database

Tags: hyperledger-explorer

After couple of trials, I was able to connect the hyperledger explorer to my blockchain network, but the process is failing while inserting the transactions into the postgre SQL DB,
Here is the [LOG](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mevjf4ifba6ek4t/console.log-2018-07-15.log?dl=0)

HERE is the [db.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jmxfiqkkccbijg4/db.log?dl=0)

Can you help me on how to resolve this issue?

The error is :

> [2018-07-15 15:19:44.140] [ERROR] pgservice - [INSERT ERROR] -  index
>   row requires 291056 bytes, maximum size is 8191

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue by droping the index (transaction_chaincode_proposal_input_idx) on table transactions
When you have a bit big JSON transaction, then this problem occurs.

The script for the index that I have dropped:

> CREATE INDEX transaction_chaincode_proposal_input_idx   ON
>   transactions   USING btree   (chaincode_proposal_input COLLATE
>   pg_catalog."default");